# Rake 10.0.3 runs the wrong version of Ruby in RVM

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rvm

I ran `bundle update rails` on an RVM-based app today, and it updated Rake to 10.0.3 in the process. Now I can't run `rake spec` anymore because it's trying to use the system Ruby instead of the correct RVM Ruby.

Here's the output:

```
$ bundle exec rake spec -b
/usr/local/lib/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb ...
rake aborted!
/usr/local/lib/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb ...
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:156:in `run_task'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:124:in `initialize'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:61:in `verbose'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:122:in `send'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:122:in `initialize'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `execute'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => spec
```

Notice that RSpec is trying to shell out to `/usr/local/lib/ruby` instead of the proper path to the RVM-installed Ruby. If I just run `rspec` from the command line, everything passes:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
.....................................

Finished in 1.81 seconds
37 examples, 0 failures
```

I downgraded to Rake 10.0.2 and didn't have this problem, and I'm able to replicate it with Rake 10.0.3 in other apps on similar Ruby versions on my local machine.

The problem seems to be that `Rake::TaskLib::RUBY` is incorrectly defined:

```
$ bundle exec ruby -e 'require "rake/tasklib"; puts Rake::TaskLib::RUBY'
/usr/local/lib/ruby
```

Any idea what's wrong with my environment?

```
OS X 10.8.2
RVM 1.18.5
```

---

**Edit:** More environment:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/bin:/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@global/bin:/Users/brandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin:/Users/brandan/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/brandan/bin:.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/pear/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ which -a ruby
/Users/brandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which -a bundle
/Users/brandan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@bcl/bin/bundle
/Users/brandan/.rvm/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
$ head -n 1 $(which bundle)
#!/Users/brandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/ruby
```

Comment: please also add to the question `echo $PATH`, `which ruby` and `head -n 1 $(which bundle)`.

Comment: @mpapis Thanks for the response. I've added some more environment to my question.

Comment: you missed to add `head -n 1 $(which bundle)`

Comment: @mpapis Sorry, I've added that too. It looks correct. I feel like the problem has to be with Rake, because Rake 10.0.2 doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you could be affected by this change https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/commit/968682759b3b65e42748cd2befb2ff3e982272d9#L0R9

make sure to unset the variable:

```
unset RUBY
```

Comment: Nailed it! I was exporting `RUBY` in `~/.bashrc` from who knows when. I removed that line and Rake works again. Thanks!